# Stop Mathematica from expanding Dirichlet beta and eta functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

It seems that Mathematica treats `DirichletBeta[s]` and `DirichletEta[s]` merely as symbols for `4^(-s) (Zeta[s, 1/4] - Zeta[s, 3/4])` and `(1-2^(1-s)) Zeta[s]` and always expands them automatically. In addition, evaluating `DirichletEta'[1]` gives a message and `Indeterminate`, while it should be `EulerGamma Log[2] - Log[2]^2/2`.

In a long expression only involving lots of `DirichletBeta` or `DirichletEta` functions, that makes the expression hard to read and some computation to fail.

Is there a way to let it not expand them while keeping their functional properties, i.e. they can still evaluate input and their derivatives properly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but an extended comment. Hopefully useful.

Well, you should have tried

```
D[DirichletEta[x], x] // Limit[#, x -> 1] &
```

which outputs

[image: res]

The other thing you can do is

```
DirichletBeta[s] // HoldForm
DirichletEta[s] // HoldForm
```

which returns

> [image: res2]

You can massage the expression that you get as much as you want by hand and then `ReleaseHold`

Comment: I have already tried the methods you mentioned above. When working with very long expressions, the limit in the first approach may take a lot of time while by some means assigning a value for `DirichletEta'[1]` can do the same much quicker. When differentiating `HoldForm[f[x]]` , `HoldForm[]` is also differentiated, which causes issues.

Comment: @Po1ynomial if `Limit` is slow is `FullSimplify@Normal@(D[DirichletEta[x], x] // Series[#, {x, 1, 0}] &)
` faster for your purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Inactivate also works.

```
DirichletBeta[s] //
Inactivate //
Echo //
D[#, s]& //
Echo //
Activate
```